# count of null with aggregate

Tags: oracle

In Oracle I have a stored procedure that queries a table and writes 2 fields into variables. Problem is Oracle will throw an error when nothing is returned. Here is my code

```
  SELECT COUNT (empno),Name
    INTO empcount,empname
    FROM lv_request_header
   WHERE empno = emp 
     AND request_id = rqid
   GROUP BY empname
```

Using NVL with a count still throws an error

ERROR at line 1: ORA-20000: lv_request_header not found ORA-06512: at line 13

Comment: How can it put a blank record into a variable?

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: lv_request_header not found
ORA-06512: at line 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you posted indicates that the problem is that the table `lv_request_header` does not exist or that the owner of the procedure does not have access to it.  If a user other than the owner of the procedure owns this table, you likely need to qualify the table name with the schema name or to create a synonym for the object.

In general, if you want to deal with a `SELECT ... INTO` statement that returns 0 rows, you'd need to specify what values you want your two local variables to have in that case.  If you want `empcount` to be 0 and `empname` to be NULL, you could do something like this

```
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT (empno),Name
    INTO empcount,empname
    FROM lv_request_header
   WHERE empno = emp 
     AND request_id = rqid
   GROUP BY empname
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found
  THEN
    empcount := 0;
    empname  := NULL;
END;
```

Comment: I have more code that comes after the select into query. My question is does the exception handling go all the way at the botton of the procedure or would my remaining code come after the excpeption handling?

Comment: @user1345246 - The exception handler is part of the `BEGIN ... END` block.  So execution would continue with the next line of code assuming that you wrap the `SELECT` statement in its own PL/SQL block as I've done here.